# Instagram API for search users

Tags: instagram-api

I work on application with Instagram API. Today I have problem with searching users

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=john&access_token=6714600555.af81720.58e232564ed94361a8d78a77cfdfce5f`

I got this error

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "APINotFoundError",
    "error_message": "this user does not exist"
  }
}
```

Do you know where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

User search was deprecated 4th of April 2018. Many endpoints have been deprecated since the Cambridge Analytica data scandal.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: I referred the Platform Changelog. But i need API for get the public user Instagram stories .